# Partial row reduction of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

I have an $m\times n$ matrix (presumably of full rank) with $m>n$, and I would like to row reduce it, but leave the last column unreduced; that is, I want to get output on the form

$\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 & \ast \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \ast}$

instead of

$\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 }$

which is what RowReduce gives me.

I can't seem to mangle RowReduce into doing it, and I would really like to avoid manually implementing the algorithm. Is there some nice way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Have you tried the methods provided to the function?

Comment: If you're asking about the Methods option for RowReduce, they all give the default output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Augmenting the matrix with the identity matrix keeps track of the row reduction.**  Thus, row-reduce just the first three columns of the matrix and use the augmentation to row-reduce the original matrix in the same way:

```
(a = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {5, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  -4 & 0 & -4 & -2 \\
>  -2 & -3 & 1 & 4 \\
>  -4 & 1 & 5 & -4 \\
>  -5 & -3 & 2 & 3 \\
>  4 & 2 & 5 & 0
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
(b = RowReduce[Join[a[[All, 1 ;; 3]], IdentityMatrix[Length@a], 2]] ) // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{19}{119} & \frac{5}{119} & \frac{1}{7} \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{33}{119} & -\frac{40}{119} & -\frac{1}{7} \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{119} & \frac{12}{119} & \frac{1}{7} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{4}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{8}{7} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{59}{119} & -\frac{122}{119} & -\frac{2}{7}
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
b[[All, 4 ;;]] . a // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{13}{17} \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{36}{17} \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{4}{17} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{18}{17}
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Comment: Thanks, that works. I guess it won't be too efficient (my matrices are rather huge), but it does at least give me the right output.

Comment: Matrix multiplication tends to be extremely fast. The join will be fast, too.  Row-reducing the augmented matrix should (roughly) double the work and obviously doubles the RAM requirements.